# Класс well (Bootstrap) на всю длину страницы

Tags: css, bootstrap

День добрый.

Подскажите пожалуйста, какое свойство в стилях `div` элемента с классом `well` библиотеки `Bootstrap` должно быть изменено, чтобы "стена" `well` была на всю длину страницы, игнорируя размер содержимых строк таблицы?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: min-height, max-height, margin - все перепробовал. Может, как-то неправильно пробовал. Пожалуйста, поправьте.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"well" - это "колодец". ("стена" была бы "wall").

Добавьте ему свойство `min-height: 100vh;`. Например, так:

```css
.well.well-tall {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="well well-tall">Well высотой не меньше, чем экран</div>
```

Comment: Дядя, сто лет живи.